# How to convert a string to const void* in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I have a method, one of whose parameters require a `const void*` as input.

When i do this, it works -

```
const void *a = "abc"; \\abc is also a string though.
```

I've tried assigning a string variable to a const void* variable, but it gave some errors.
Why can't i directly assign a string variable to a `const void*` variable?

How can i convert a string to a `const void*` ?

Is there any other way around ?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want a "const void*" and not a "const char*"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If by "string", you mean `std::string`, then that's a class type, which isn't directly convertible to a pointer. A string literal like `"abc"` is a character array, which is convertible to a pointer.

If you want a pointer to the string's character array, then you can access that via the `c_str` function:

```
const void * a = my_string.c_str();
```

Beware that the pointer can become invalid if you destroy or modify the string.

Comment: @Ashish you need to explicitly copy the string if you need to use it after the destruction/modifying of the original `std::string` using strcpy or something similar

Answer (score 0):

An `std::string` is bigger than a `void *` and therefore will not fit in it.
You can pass the c-string representation (`string.c_str()`) or the address of the string(`&string`) to the `void *`. In both cases you need to make sure that the `void *` does not access the `string` after the `string` disappears or changes.